# TkInter crashes when called through gRPC

Tags: python, tkinter, grpc

### Setup

- macOS Big Sur
- Python 3.9.5
- main dependencies

```
grpcio = "^1.41.0"
grpcio-tools = "^1.41.0"
grpcio-reflection = "^1.41.0"
```

### Problem

I have a simple Python script using TkInter that works under commandline mode, but crashes when the module gets called using gRPC.

### Code

The TkInter related code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as tkfiledialog

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    
    root.withdraw()
    root.after_idle(prompt, root)
    root.mainloop()

def prompt(root):
    return tkfiledialog.askopenfilename(
        parent=root,
        title="Select Files",
        filety[es=[("All Files", "*")],
        defaultextension=("All Files", "*"),
        multiple=True,
    )
```

The gRPC architecture is quite standard that I don't think is worth posting.
It has little to do with my client implementation as well, because I can easily reproduce the crash using grpcurl

```sh
grpcurl -d '{"dryrun": false, "verbose": false, "startdir": ".", "dironly": false, "filepatterns": "*" }' -plaintext localhost:57728 selectfilesfolders.SelectFilesFolders.SelectFilesFolders
```

### Crash log

```
2021-10-10 16:06:50.147 Python[2855:90390] WARNING: NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread! This will throw an exception in the future. Called from (
    0   AppKit                              0x00007fff22e55ed1 -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 352
    1   AppKit                              0x00007fff22e40aa2 -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1296
    2   AppKit                              0x00007fff23002c2f -[NSPanel _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 50
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff22e4058b -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 42
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff23002be4 -[NSPanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 64
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff2384e274 -[NSSavePanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 97
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff2385636d -[NSOpenPanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 151
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff2314f0e5 -[NSPanel init] + 75
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff2384e1f0 -[NSSavePanel init] + 197
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff23522c3a +[NSSavePanel(Instantiation) _crunchyRawUnbonedPanel] + 58
    10  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x0000000102b97a11 Tk_GetOpenFileObjCmd + 67
    11  libtcl8.6.dylib                     0x00000001029886dc TclNRRunCallbacks + 80
    12  _tkinter.cpython-39-darwin.so       0x0000000102961029 Tkapp_Call + 585
    13  Python                              0x000000010123245d cfunction_call + 125
    14  Python                              0x00000001011f3a3c _PyObject_Call + 140
    15  Python                              0x00000001012c7a73 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27027
    16  Python                              0x00000001012cab33 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2611
    17  Python                              0x00000001011f3c41 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 289
    18  Python                              0x00000001012c9e3c call_function + 732
    19  Python                              0x00000001012c7342 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25186
    20  Python                              0x00000001012cab33 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2611
    21  Python                              0x00000001011f3c41 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 289
    22  Python                              0x00000001012c9e3c call_function + 732
    23  Python                              0x00000001012c7491 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25521
    24  Python                              0x00000001011f3cb8 function_code_fastcall + 104
    25  Python                              0x00000001011f5de9 method_vectorcall + 441
    26  Python                              0x00000001012c7a73 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27027
    27  Python                              0x00000001012cab33 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2611
    28  Python                              0x00000001011f3c41 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 289
    29  Python                              0x00000001012c7a73 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27027
    30  Python                              0x00000001012cab33 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2611
    31  Python                              0x00000001011f3c41 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 289
    32  Python                              0x00000001011f5d42 method_vectorcall + 274
    33  _tkinter.cpython-39-darwin.so       0x0000000102963bb1 PythonCmd + 209
    34  libtcl8.6.dylib                     0x00000001029886dc TclNRRunCallbacks + 80
    35  libtcl8.6.dylib                     0x0000000102a54ed3 AfterProc + 83
    36  libtcl8.6.dylib                     0x0000000102a54570 TclServiceIdle + 87
    37  libtcl8.6.dylib                     0x0000000102a37d27 Tcl_DoOneEvent + 349
    38  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x0000000102b1aa02 MapFrame + 40
    39  libtcl8.6.dylib                     0x0000000102a54570 TclServiceIdle + 87
    40  libtcl8.6.dylib                     0x0000000102a37d27 Tcl_DoOneEvent + 349
    41  _tkinter.cpython-39-darwin.so       0x00000001029633de _tkinter_tkapp_mainloop + 382
    42  Python                              0x00000001011fc3df method_vectorcall_FASTCALL + 335
    43  Python                              0x00000001012c9e3c call_function + 732
    44  Python                              0x00000001012c7342 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25186
    45  Python                              0x00000001012cab33 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2611
    46  Python                              0x00000001011f3c41 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 289
    47  Python                              0x00000001011f5cfa method_vectorcall + 202
    48  Python                              0x00000001012c9e3c call_function + 732
    49  Python                              0x00000001012c7363 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25219
    50  Python                              0x00000001011f3cb8 function_code_fastcall + 104
    51  Python                              0x00000001012c9e3c call_function + 732
    52  Python                              0x00000001012c7342 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25186
    53  Python                              0x00000001011f3cb8 function_code_fastcall + 104
    54  Python                              0x00000001012c7a73 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27027
    55  Python                              0x00000001012cab33 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2611
    56  Python                              0x00000001011f3c41 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 289
    57  Python                              0x00000001012c9e3c call_function + 732
    58  Python                              0x00000001012c7363 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25219
    59  Python                              0x00000001011f3cb8 function_code_fastcall + 104
    60  Python                              0x00000001011f5cfa method_vectorcall + 202
    61  Python                              0x00000001012c9e3c call_function + 732
    62  Python                              0x00000001012c73fb _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25371
    63  Python                              0x00000001012cab33 _PyEval_EvalCode + 2611
    64  Python                              0x00000001011f3c41 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 289
    65  Python                              0x00000001012c9e3c call_function + 732
    66  Python                              0x00000001012c73fb _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25371
    67  Python                              0x00000001011f3cb8 function_code_fastcall + 104
    68  Python                              0x00000001012c7a73 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27027
    69  Python                              0x00000001011f3cb8 function_code_fastcall + 104
    70  Python                              0x00000001012c9e3c call_function + 732
    71  Python                              0x00000001012c7342 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25186
    72  Python                              0x00000001011f3cb8 function_code_fastcall + 104
    73  Python                              0x00000001012c7a73 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27027
    74  Python                              0x00000001011f3cb8 function_code_fastcall + 104
    75  Python                              0x00000001012c9e3c call_function + 732
    76  Python                              0x00000001012c7342 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25186
    77  Python                              0x00000001011f3cb8 function_code_fastcall + 104
    78  Python                              0x00000001012c9e3c call_function + 732
    79  Python                              0x00000001012c7342 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25186
    80  Python                              0x00000001011f3cb8 function_code_fastcall + 104
    81  Python                              0x00000001011f5d42 method_vectorcall + 274
    82  Python                              0x000000010136ec56 t_bootstrap + 70
    83  Python                              0x0000000101320169 pythread_wrapper + 25
    84  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff2052c8fc _pthread_start + 224
    85  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff20528443 thread_start + 15
)
```

### Workaround

- If I replace the TkInter part with ANY code, everything works.
- Call this with IPC through child process works as well

### Question

How should I go about debugging or should this be a sign that TkInter is not proper for my task?

Comment: The gRPC call will never return due to `mainloop()` until the window is destroyed.

Comment: @acw1668 Is that the cause of the crash? Would it mean that any GUI program is bound to fail with gRPC? I assume normally any local function call would allow indefinite blocking hehaviours, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this GitHub anwser](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/27673)

It is likely a macOS-specific threading issue

> On the other hand, according to tkinter's [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#architecture). The library may have
> special event handling logic and threading restrictions, and gRPC
> Python uses a thread pool to handle incoming requests with gRPC Core
> handling the IO.

By digging into that doc, we find

> A Python interpreter may have many threads associated with it. In Tcl,
> multiple threads can be created, but each thread has a separate Tcl
> interpreter instance associated with it. Threads can also create more
> than one interpreter instance, though each interpreter instance can be
> used only by the one thread that created it.
>
> Each Tk object created by tkinter contains a Tcl interpreter. It also
> keeps track of which thread created that interpreter. Calls to tkinter
> can be made from any Python thread. Internally, if a call comes from a
> thread other than the one that created the Tk object, an event is
> posted to the interpreter’s event queue, and when executed, the result
> is returned to the calling Python thread.

Although I'm not an expert on platform-specific threading models, I do know that macOS is using a "Grand Central Dispatch" task-queue system that hides away a lot of thread-pool details, which is different from Windows.

Thus, without digging into gRPC's thread-pool model, I can't say it's safe to call Tkinter widgets, who keep track of thread that create them, from the volatile gRPC's I/O threads.